# How can I display a TemporaryUploadedFile from Django in HTML as an image?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

In Django, I have programmed a form in which you can upload one image. After uploading the image, the image is passed to another method with the type TemporaryUploadedFile, after executing the method it is given to the HTML page.

What I would like to do is display that TemporaryUploadedFile as an image in HTML. It sounds quite simple to me but I could not find the answer on StackOverflow or on Google to the question: How to display a TemporaryUploadedFile in HTML without having to save it first, hence my question.

All help is appreciated.

---

**Edit 1:**

To give some more information about the code and the variables while debugging.

```
input_image = next(iter(request.FILES.values()))
output_b64 = (input_image.content_type, str(base64.b64encode(input_image.read()), 'utf8'))
```

[image: Debug information]

Comment: Well, it's strange. The size of the image is around 4 MB, but the encoded string is only a few bytes. I'm guessing `input_image.read()` is not reading the whole file because it's larger than 2.5 MB and Django is dividing this file into chunks. Can you try this with a smaller image, with a few hundred kilobytes and tell me if that works. I might need to add another answer if that's the problem.

Comment: I resized the image, now its size is 116KB. I also tried it with some images from Google. Just to check that the set of images that I am using is not in any way corrupted. It's a pity but it did not do the trick, the image still isn't displayed. I wonder what the cause could be.

Comment: Hi, I just tested this with Django 2.0, Python 3.6, and everything works fine for me, with large and small images, alike. I've no idea why it isn't working for you. But I hope you'll figure it out. All the best.

Comment: I want to thank you for your help. I am going to try and fix it, at least I know now that it should work so it is likely that the problem is somewhere else in my application and when I fix it I post the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank xyres for pushing me in the right direction. As you can see, I used some parts of his solution in the code below:

```
# As input I take one image from the form.
temp_uploaded_file = next(iter(request.FILES.values()))

# The TemporaryUploadedFile is converted to a Pillow Image
input_image = pil_image.open(temp_uploaded_file)

# The input image does not have a name so I set it afterwards. (This step, of course, is not mandatory)
input_image.filename = temp_uploaded_file.name

# The image is saved to an InMemoryFile
output = BytesIO()
input_image.save(output, format=img.format)

# Then the InMemoryFile is encoded
img_data = str(base64.b64encode(output.getvalue()), 'utf8')
output_b64 = ('image/' + img.format, img_data)

# Pass it to the template
return render(request, 'visualsearch/similarity_output.html', {
    "output_image": output_b64
})
```

In the template:

```
<img id="output_image" src="data:{{ image.0 }};base64,{{ image.1 }}">
```

The current solution works but I don't think it is perfect because I expect that it can be done with less code and faster, so if you know how this can be done better you are welcome to post your answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can encode the image to `base64` and use a data url as the value for `src`.

A base64 data url looks like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,SGLAFdsfsafsf098sflf">
               \_______/        \__________________/
                   |                     |
                File type        base64 encoded data
```

Read the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) for more on data urls.

Here's some relevant code:

```
import base64

def my_view(request):
    # assuming `image` is a <TemporaryUploadedFile object>
    
    image_b64 = base64.b64encode(image.read())
    image_b64 = image_b64.decode('utf8') # convert bytes to string
    image_type = image.content_type # png or jpeg or something else
    return render('template', {'image_b64': image_b64, 'image_type': image_type})
```

Then in your template:

```
<img src="data:{{ image_type }};base64,{{ image_b64 }}">
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I ran into the issue, that when generating the image src it looks like this in the HTML: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,b'puGSpAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='">`. The string in the src looks quite odd compared to yours, not only because it had a "b" with two apostrophes in it indicating that it is a byte string but also because of the two equal-signs at the end. Could you help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @user3473161 Oh, yes. You must be using Python 3. base64 encoded objects are bytes-like objects in Python 3 as opposed to str-like objects in Python 2. That is why there's a `b` in the beginning. I'll update my answer with a solution soon.

Comment: I am looking forward to that :p. Yea, at the moment I am using the 64-bit version of Python 3.6.3.

Comment: I hope I am not bothering you too much, but I was unable to fix it. To provide some more information on what's going wrong I put a tiny piece of code in my question and the information from the debugger.

Comment: The updated solution for Python 3 worked beautifully for me. Thank you!